# How to hide all the names of small towns on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As you know all the names of the large cities with big population are displayed with the large font size and all the names of the small towns are displayed with the small font size. How can I hide all the names of small towns with little population on the map at my website by using API Google Maps?

Answer (score 6):

from the [styled map wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/), turn off the "Labels" for neighborhood, locality and parcel:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
  }
]
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtwaL0az/)

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles: [{
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {}]
    });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant not to turn off ALL the labels but only labels of small towns with population less than N thousands for example less than 50 000

Comment: You only have two options that I know of in that case: 1. turn off all the labels, add your own that meet your criteria; 2. use the classes of towns defined by the API (neighborhood, locality,... as my example).